# Manipulating video in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, youtube

I am building a web application where I will have multiple videos. But besides that there are also plenty of other things I want to be able to do, like click on video and save a video tag, then it will show up next time for other users who see the video (like youtube). Or pause the video, get the time where it is paused and then add a comment to it and save the time and the comment on my database.

Is it possible to do with just ruby on rails or do I need to use api or use other stuff? I will also want to do a bit more complex video manipulations but for now this ones are enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am citing an example for the general HTML5 video tag, which supports few of the popular video formats. But this will be applicable across other popular video players like flowplayer as well

Have a look at [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop)

You can send an ajax at every button(play/pause) press to your controller, which will save the details of the time at the which video was paused, so you can record that in your database. This [link](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) will give you an example of most of the properties, that you can play with :)

Comment: I'm not using html5 to see the video, but video_tag from ruby on rails. Can I do the same?

Comment: yes, video_tag helper in rails generates the HTML5 <video> tag, its the same tag being used in the 2nd link. Can you have a look at it again. It should resolved your doubts :)

Comment: will do it today ;) then will get back to you thanks!